# Is connection to SMTP server secure?

Tags: ssl, smtp

I would like to be sure on a point about connection to an SMTP server.

If I am using SSL to connect to an SMTP server, are my password and username encrypted to connect to the SMTP server ?

Thank you for your help

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be. Either your server should require the entire SMTP session to be SSL, or, after the initial connection, your SMTP session will switch to SSL.

I've never known a SMTP server that required SSL, that didn't encrypt the creds.